# How to join on customDimensions in Application Insights Analytics?

Tags: join, azure-application-insights

When I try to join on one of the customDimensions fields, I get a syntax error: "join attributes may be only column entity or equality expressions".  I am able to join on non-custom columns such as name or timestamp.

Sample code:

```js
let ExperimentLaunchedEvents = customEvents | where name=="ExperimentLaunched" and timestamp > now(-30d);  

let ExperimentTerminatedEvents = customEvents | where name=="ExperimentTerminated" and timestamp > now(-30d); 

ExperimentLaunchedEvents  
    | project name, timestamp, experimentId=customDimensions.ExperimentId  
    | join kind=leftanti (ExperimentTerminatedEvents  
                            | project name, timestamp, experimentId=customDimensions.ExperimentId) on tostring(experimentId)
```

If joining on customDimensions columns is not supported, is there any way to achieve selecting launched experiments that haven't been terminated?  Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned by John in the comments When using custom dimensions for any operations you need to convert it to a type that can be used by the query engine. In this case I use [tostring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#tostring), but you can also use other functions like [toint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#toint).

I also extend a column type so it can be reused in clauses like join or where without having to use the long hand over and over again.

```
ExperimentLaunchedEvents
| extend experimentId=tostring(customDimensions.ExperimentId)
| project name, timestamp, experimentId
| join kind=leftanti (ExperimentTerminatedEvents
| extend experimentId=tostring(customDimensions.ExperimentId)
| project name, timestamp, experimentId)
on experimentId
```

Comment: it's more than the extend, the `tostring` is actually the important thing here.  analytics joins only let you join on "known" types, and by default customDimensions itself is effectively an "any" or "custom" or "json" type that the things inside could be anything.

Comment: John is correct. The tostring function takes the dynamic type and casts it to one that is consumable. Updating answer with this.

Comment: It seems that you can only use the variable experimentId on the join clause, if you use the same variable on the project clause. Do you know a way of doing that without putting experimentId  in the project clause? I don't want to show the column on the results, but I want to use it in the join.

Answer (score 0):

Same as James Davis answer, but a minor enhancement of stopping the experimentId column repeating twice due to its inclusion in both the project clauses, as pointed out by squallsv

```
let myExperimentLauncedEvents=
    ExperimentLaunchedEvents
        | extend experimentId=tostring(customDimensions.ExperimentId)
        | project name, timestamp, experimentId
        | join kind=leftanti (ExperimentTerminatedEvents
        | extend experimentId=tostring(customDimensions.ExperimentId)
        | project name, timestamp, experimentId)
    on experimentId;
myExperimentLauncedEvents
    | project name, timestamp, experimentId
```

As a result, by assigning the result to a [variable (temp table)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour#lethttpsdocsloganalyticsiodocslanguage-referencequery-statementslet-statement-assign-a-result-to-a-variable), and then using the project clause on that variable, we can choose to display only those columns that are required.